# Calculating Normalized Difference Infrared Index from Sentinel-2 data

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, vegetation-index

is it possible to use Normalized Difference Infrared Index together with sentinel 2 to develop soil moisture map?
If possible, let me know the formula of NDII.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Did you search online for the formula? I believe it's fairly easy to acquire the formula for the index using Sentinel-2 data if you just Google it using the right keywords.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently yes.

Sriwongsitanon et. al. [1] state that NDII can be a proxy for root zone water content, and an Sentinel Hub example script [2] states that the index can be calculated from bands 8 and 11 of Sentinel-2 like this:

```
index = (B08 - B11) / (B08 + B11);
```

[1] Sriwongsitanon, N., Gao, H., Savenije, H. H. G., Maekan, E., Saengsawang, S., & Thianpopirug, S. (2015). The Normalized Difference Infrared Index (NDII) as a proxy for soil moisture storage in hydrological modelling. Copernicus GmbH. https://doi.org/10.5194/hessd-12-8419-2015

[2] https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/ndii/